# Apache Beam's BigQueryIO (Java): Can't write TIMESTAMP fields to BigQuery -- fasterxml.jackson exception "type not supported"

Tags: java, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I'm trying `BigQueryIO.write<T>()` using code samples from Apache Beam's Guide ([BigQuery I/O connector](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#writing-to-a-table)) and [BigQueryIO javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.29.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html), both seem to have an example with some `Quote` class that has a field of java `Instant` type (it's unclear whether it's `java.time.Instant`, or `org.joda.time.Instant`),

however, I'm getting an exception from Jackson saying "type not supported", and I can't get it to work no matter what, full stack below.

I have no idea where I could "add the com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda module" in my pipeline. Any ideas?

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Joda date/time type `org.joda.time.Instant` not supported by default: add Module "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda" to enable handling (through reference chain: com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow["timestamp"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1276)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnsupportedTypeSerializer.serialize(UnsupportedTypeSerializer.java:35)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:808)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithoutTypeInfo(MapSerializer.java:764)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:720)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:35)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._writeValueAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4487)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3742)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowJsonCoder.encode(TableRowJsonCoder.java:45)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowJsonCoder.encode(TableRowJsonCoder.java:32)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowWriter.write(TableRowWriter.java:42)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteBundlesToFiles.processElement(WriteBundlesToFiles.java:232)
```

Code is like this:

```
 class Quote {
   final Instant timestamp;
   final String exchange;
   final String symbol;
   final double price;

   Quote(Instant timestamp, String exchange, String symbol, double price) {
     // initialize all member variables.
   }
 }

 PCollection<Quote> quotes = ...

 quotes.apply(BigQueryIO
     .<Quote>write()
     .to("my-project:my_dataset.my_table")
     .withSchema(new TableSchema().setFields(
         ImmutableList.of(
           new TableFieldSchema().setName("timestamp").setType("TIMESTAMP"),
           new TableFieldSchema().setName("exchange").setType("STRING"),
           new TableFieldSchema().setName("symbol").setType("STRING"),
           new TableFieldSchema().setName("price").setType("FLOAT"))))
     .withFormatFunction(quote -> new TableRow().set(..set the columns..))
     .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE));
```

Comment: Are you missing "jackson_databind" dependency somehow ? For example, if you are using Maven,  

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @chamikara -- I do have both `jackson-databind` and `jackson-datatype-joda` in my  pom.xml

Comment: note, if I comment out the Instant/TIMESTAMP field, then everything works, and I do get rows written to BQ

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert Instant (java.time.Instant or org.joda.time.Instant) to String using toString() while creating TableRow object and it would work.

For reference, the sample createTableRow method in the documentation covers the expected format for all supported types: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#data-types

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that's sooo bad! I can't believe I got a type error if I use the proper type. And registering the joda serializer for some reason have no effect.